# How to temporarily stop mobx from triggering observers?

Tags: mobx

I am using mobx for my datastructure (not with React). I need to make a change to an observable property to analyse the structure with this changed value. After analysis I undo the change and go back to the original state.

I wrapped the "*change observed value and change back observed value*" in a mobx action using `runInAction`.  As the observable property has the same value before and after the `runInAction` I was expecting (or maybe rather hoping) that mobx would understand this and not trigger any observers. As it is, mobx does see the change(s) to the observable value inside the `runInAction`  and the observers are triggered.

Is there another way to stop mobx from triggering observers temporarily?

Comment: If you just need to check some new structure, why would you need to assign new value to observable property? Could you just make deep copy of it and do whatever you want with it?

Comment: I could make a deep copy indeed, but the structure can be quite large and copying it is too expensive. Also the result of the analysis appeard in a popup menu the user is waiting for, so being really really quick is important.

Comment: Well, there is no such build in method in MobX, so you would need to do something different.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** After further investigation the `intercept` approach will not work. [As the docs say](https://mobx.js.org/actions.html#updating-state-using-actions), any code wrapped in an action block "will be run until the outer-most action has finished, guaranteeing that intermediate or incomplete values produced during an action are not visible to the rest of the application until the action has completed". While this *delays* the reactions, it does not *batch* them.

This is further illustrated in this [crude sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/8jrwu) which makes a change (adds a new row), analyses the change (checks if total >= 500) and reverts the change if so. If the change is reverted, the autorun block will be triggered twice after the action block is complete.

---

##### Original Answer

The MobX `intercept` function may provide the necessary hook into the propagation of the change event allowing you to prevent observers from firing. From the [MobX docs: Intercept & Observe](https://mobx.js.org/intercept-and-observe.html#intercept):

> `intercept` can be used to detect and modify mutations before they are applied to the observable
>
> **Usage**: `intercept(target, propertyName?, interceptor)`

Specifically, by writing your interceptor in a way that catches the change event emitted from the code in your `runInAction` block, you should be able to prevent further propagation. By returning `null` from your interceptor function:

> this indicates that the change can be ignored and shouldn't be applied. This is a powerful concept to make your objects for example temporarily immutable.

This may be as simple as detecting that `change.oldValue === change.newValue`, but without more information it is hard to say. Hopefully this gives you a possible path forward in solving your problem.

#### Other Approaches

The "Intercept & Observe" page on mobx.js.org comes with the following warnings:

> ⚠️ Warning: intercept and observe are low level utilities, and should not be needed in practice ... Using these utilities is an anti-pattern ... ⚠️

###### intercept

> [intercept] Please avoid this API. It basically provides a bit of aspect-oriented programming, creating flows that are really hard to debug. Instead, do things like data validation before updating any state, rather than during.

For that reason, I encourage you to look to see if one of the following will solve your problem:

- Manipulate and Analyze a deep copy of the observable
- [snapshots](https://mobx-state-tree.js.org/concepts/snapshots) + time travel with mobx-state-tree

Comment: But how would `intercept` help here? If you return `null` then there will be no change at all? If there is no change then how would you analyse new structure?

Comment: My understanding is that OP has an existing function where `action(() => doChange(), analyzeChange(), revertChange())`, and the goal is to prevent any changes resulting from `doChange` + `revertChange` from triggering additional observers. The code in the `action` block _should_ only trigger a single observable change event, so as I understand, `intercept` should allow op to "stop mobx from triggering observers temporarily"

Comment: But if you return `null` the change won't be applied and `analyzeChange` won't see it? Maybe I am missing something, but in my understanding this won't work.

Comment: @Danila You are right, this solution stops the change from being applied and the analysis can't take place.

Comment: @PatrickFowler I have looked into mobx-state-tree,  but it is too opiniated and does not quite fit into the way we use mobx.

Comment: @JosWarmer Per the docs: "[Actions] are run inside transactions. No reactions will be run until the outer-most action has finished, guaranteeing that intermediate or incomplete values produced during an action are not visible to the rest of the application until the action has completed." This sandbox (https://8jrwu.csb.app) shows that although the reactions are delayed, indeed **two** reactions are fired when you try to add a user w/ salary >= 125, making the intercept approach non-tenable